# How to get output of neural network without using matlab nn toolbox?

Tags: matlab

I create and then train a network with following lines:

```
% here input is 9x543, target is 2x543 and hidden is 6 and output has 2 neurons
net = newff(input,target,{hidden},{'logsig','logsig'},'trainlm'); 
[net,tr] = train(net,input,target);
```

After training phase, I simulate my network with following line:

```
out1 = sim(net,input);
```

Then I get weights of network with following lines:

```
iwNet = net.IW{1,1};
lwNet = net.LW{2,1};
b1Net = net.b{1,1};
b2Net = net.b{2,1};
```

I implement my own network to get predicted output of input values:

```
% here input is 543x9 and target is 543x2
out2=logsig(logsig(input*iw'+repmat(b1',size(input,1),1))*lw'+repmat(b2',size(input,1),1));
```

I was expecting to be out1==out2, since I am using same activation functions, weights, and bias. But out2 has very interesting results. (still 1st column is 1 and second column of output is zero)

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be pre-processing functions.  Check if you included any:

```
net.inputs{1}.processFcns
```